# Cargar datos a un TextBox desde SQL con programacion C# 3 capas Web Form

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, webforms

Necesito llenar un text box con un dato que tengo en mi base de datos SQL, estoy programando en C# 3 capas web form, no sé si se puede realizar con List<> o con DataTable.

Codigo de ejemplo:

```
public List<Cliente> ListadoCodigo()
    {
        SqlConnection con = null;
        SqlCommand cmd = null;
        SqlDataReader dr = null;
        List<Cliente> listaCodigo = new List<Cliente>();
        try
        {
            con = Conexion.getInstance().ConexionDB();
            cmd = new SqlCommand("USP_LISTACODIGO", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            con.Open();
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                Cliente cliente = new Cliente();
                cliente.ID = dr["Codigo"].ToString();;
                listaCodigo.Add(cliente);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
        return listaCodigo;
    }
```

Ese codigo quiero mostrarlo en mi Texbox.

Comment: Se puede hacer como quieras. no hay restricciones. Que intentaste y que problema particular tuviste?

Comment: Hasta el momento que es lo que llevas, si llenaras el textbox con un solo dato para que quieres un List o DataTable, ?

Comment: En mi BD tengo una tabla Cliente, en la que quiero pasar el Id a una caja de Texto. Normalmente lo hago con un List en la capa Datos, pero mi dificultad es al mostrarlo en el TexBox. Tengo que poner txtid. ? = ?

Comment: ¿Podrías editar tu pregunta agregando todo el código que has intentado?

Comment: Ya agregue la manera en la que estaba desarrollandolo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utiliza un `List<>` si vas a programar en capas, los `DataTable` ya son anticuados.

Entonces creas la clase que represente a entidad de dominio

```
public class NombreEntiedad
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Nombre {get;set;}
}
```

Para luego cargarla desde la consulta que realizas a la db

```
public List<NombreEntiedad> GetAll()
{
    List<NombreEntiedad> result = new List<NombreEntiedad>();

    string connstring = "connection string";  
    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connstring)) {  
        cn.Open();  

        string sql = "SELECT Id, Nombre FROM Tabla";  
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn);  

        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();  

        while (reader.Read())  
        {  
            NombreEntiedad item = new NombreEntiedad();
            item.Id = Convert.ToInt32(reader["campo1"]);  
            item.Nombre = Convert.ToString(reader["campo2"]);  

            result.Add(item);
        }  
    } 

    return result;
}
```

si creas una capa de acceso a datos como esto quedara genial, nuevamente no uses datatable.

```
public NombreEntiedad GetById(int Id)
{
    NombreEntiedad entity = null;

    string connstring = "connection string";  
    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connstring)) {  
        cn.Open();  

        string sql = "SELECT Id, Nombre FROM Tabla WHERE Id = @Id";  
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn);  
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", Id);

        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();  

        if(reader.Read())  
        {  
            entity = new NombreEntiedad();
            item.Id = Convert.ToInt32(reader["campo1"]);  
            item.Nombre = Convert.ToString(reader["campo2"]);  
        }  
    } 

    return entity;
}
```

Por supuesto sino se encuenta el registro deberias validar por `null` ya que no tendras una instancia

---

Si necesitas mostrar varios datos en un textbox podrias unirlos con algun separador.

```
List<Cliente> clientes = obj.ListadoCodigo();
string Ids = string.Join(", ", clientes.Select(x=> x.ID));

TextBox1.Text = Ids;
```

Comment: Lo tengo de la misma manera, la dificultad que tengo es como poner el valor del Nombre (el que tienes en tu ejemplo) en el TextBox. Cuando tengo un DropDownList sé que tengo que definirlo como DataSource, DataTexfield, pero eso no lo puedo realizar en un TextBox.

Comment: pero es una lista, no puedes poner en un textbox, salvo que tomes un item solo. Si vas a tomar una sola entidad deberias aplicar un WHERE en la consulta que retorne una sola entidad, pero no devolverias una lista. Edito la repsuesta para poner un ejemplo

Comment: Modifique mi pregunta, para que observes maso menos como lo estaba resolviendo. Solo quiero mostrar ese codigo en un TexBox.

Comment: pero es una lista, no vas a poder mostrarla en un textbox, si en un combo o listbox, salvo que tomes un unico item o que unas co algun separador los datos para mostrarlos como string

Comment: edite la respuesta para agregar lo que comento

Comment: Si ya no quisiera utilizar una Lista, como tendría que hacerlo? Porque como puse en mi ejemplo, solo me retorna un valor. Como sería la forma adecuada para mostrar ese dato en mi TextBox?

Comment: seria `TextBox1.Text = lista[0].ID;` tomas el indice cero que es el primer valor de la lista

Comment: Muchas Gracias!